# How to call a sub class using a string variable?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reflection, runtime-type

So I have this simple for loop and I want to access a variable of a class

However there are multiple classes so that's how I ended up with for loop.

This is what my code looks like.

```
for (int i = 0; i<itemId.Length; i++)
{
    Type type = Type.GetType(" " + itemid[i]);
    object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    Debug.Log(itemResponse.data.Invoke(itemid[i]).name);
}
```

I am trying to access

```
itemResponse.data."My String".name
```

The classes I want to access are.

`public class _1001{ }`
`public class _1002{ }`
`public class _1003{ }`

and so on, is there any way I could do that?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have so many classes? And why are you just using the initially assigned values of those classes. It really seems like you've architected the application incorrectly and you're asking an XY problem type question. Please provide more information.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Please **do** include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Just have all relevant classes implement an interface with a method or property that returns that data.

Comment: Instantiating a default instance of your Type as you do in this command: `object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type)` doesn't appear to be something that will help you get where you're going.

Answer (score 1):

The Object-Oriented Programming concept of [Polymorphism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/object-oriented/polymorphism) can simplify solving your question. It's what's "under the hood" for the very excellent comment about implementing an interface.

Here's the most basic demo I can think of. I've made the three classes that you name in your post, but in addition have defined a common interface.

```
interface ICommon
{
    void LogData();
}
class _1001 : ICommon
{
    public void LogData() => 
        Console.WriteLine("Class-specific datalogging for 'class _1001'.");
}
class _1002 : ICommon
{
    public void LogData() => 
        Console.WriteLine("Class-specific datalogging for 'class _1002'.");
}
class _1003 : ICommon    
{
    public void LogData() => 
        Console.WriteLine("Class-specific datalogging for 'class _1003'.");
}
```

Each of these classes will implement the `ICommon` and in particular the `LogData` method in its own class-specific way. This holds even if we instantiate them as type `object`:

```
    object[] unknownObjects = new object[]
    {
        new _1001(),
        new _1002(),
        new _1003(),
    };
```

The interface allows for implicit casting when looping the `object[]`

```
    // Demonstrate implicit casting to an interface
    foreach (ICommon knownInterface in unknownObjects)
    {
        knownInterface.LogData();
    }
}
```

Basically, you're promising the compiler that the object you're giving it in the loop *will have* a method called `LogData`. It then proceeds to call the correct class-specific implementation without a lot of fuss and bother. And if you were to attempt it with an object that doesn't implement `ICommon` you would get an `InvalidCastException` at runtime.

The output of the loop is:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend doing this, but if you don't want to create an interface like IVSoftware recommended, this function should do what you want.

```
    static object AccessPropertyWithReflections(object obj, string propertyName)
    {
        object output = null;
        var typeInfo = obj.GetType();
        var propertyInfo = typeInfo.GetProperty(propertyName);
        if (propertyInfo is not null)
        {
            output = propertyInfo.GetValue(obj);
        }
        return output;
    }
```